# Is $\Bbb Z[1/5]$ a PID?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a question. Is $\mathbb{Z}[1/5]$ a PID? I think the element in it is of the form{a+b/$5^n$,a,b$\in\mathbb{Z}$}. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see this, observe that elements may be written $a/5^n$ by taking a common denominator, and an ideal with a generator $a/5^n$ can equally well be generated using $a$, since $5$ is a unit. So every ideal can be generated by integers, and on the subring of integers we can use the usual argument to show that such an ideal is principal. In particular, we can classify all ideals: they're just those of $\mathbb{Z}$ under the relation $(5k)=(k)$. So each ideal can be uniquely generated by $n$ where $n$ is not divisible by $5$.

Comment: The hyphen in "$a$-$5$ being a unit" can be innocently  confused with a minus. Perhaps a double hyphen will eliminate such confusion.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff thanks for the tipoff.

Comment: No problem Kevin.

Comment: I think I see what you said. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Every localization of a PID is a PID. You can use that ring is a PID iff every prime is principal, and then use the bijection of primes of $A$ that don't intersect $S$ with those of $S^{-1}A$.

Comment: I think we have good reason to doubt that the OP knows about localization. But of course your answer is the canonical one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I see what you say.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ Since $5$ is a unit, every element is associate to an integer coprime to $5$ (remove all factors of $5$ from the numerator and denominator, leaving an integer coprime to $5$), and an ideal $\ne 0$ is generated by its least positive such element - just as in $\,\Bbb Z.$